# how ingressroute is hooked up to traefik's ingress contoller

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I am learning `traefik` and `ingressroute`. One thing confused me the most is how the two parts are connected together.

After deploying `traefik` and my own service, I can simply create the following `ingressroute` to make it work:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-service-ir
  namespace: my-service-ns
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Path(`/`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: my-service
      port: 8000
```

But the `ingressroute` has nothing shared with `traefik`: not in the same namespace, no selector, etc.. It seems to me that the `ingressroute` can magically find `traefik` and apply on `traefik`. I am curious what happened behind it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy traefik in the kubernetes cluster, you use the rbac-k8s manifests like [here](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/blob/main/kubernetes/gcp/task-005-traefik-whoami/05-traefik-rbac.yml). If you use helm then these are all present under that hood.

These RBACs actually create the new resource types i.e. `IngressRoute` over here.
They are applied at cluster level as you see in the link `ClusterRole`. This gives them ClusterLevel privileges. This is the reason you don't see anything special in the namespace.

You can checkout the [sample task](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/kubernetes/gcp/task-005-traefik-whoami) here which will give some more light on the matter.